# Prevent catastrophic backtracking in this regex

Tags: c#, regex

`(\W*\d+)*(?=\W|$)`

I'm having a problem with this regex, causing the system to crash when a certain term is searched.

I'm trying to find way to remove the catastrophic backtracking without changing its logic, but so far I've got nothing.

**Term:** `0000000000000000000000000000Abc`

You can test it, and see the timeout, here:

- https://regex101.com/r/ljYPhA/1

Comment: What text do you search for? What are the pattern requirements? Please provide some examples.

Comment: Well, the only way to reliably prevent catastrophic backtracking is to stay away from certain regex patterns that are prone to it. There is no magic way to make a pattern suffering from catastrophic backtracking issues without changing it (if there was such a way, catastrophic backtracking issues would have been solved in the regex engines many, many, years ago already, don't you think?)

Comment: At least remove `+`, `(\W*\d)*(?!\w)`. The `\W` matches any non-word digit and that will enable "linear" matching.

Comment: I think that this is what I was looking for. Removing "+" will prevent the catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `+` after `\d` since otherwise, it would take regex engine too long to test all possible ways of matching a non-matching string before admitting the no match.

Use

```
(?:\W*\d)*(?!\w)
```

or

```
(?:\W*\d)*\b
```

The `\W` matches any non-word char (so, no digit) and when `d` is matched, `\W*` will consume 0 or more non-word chars enabling a "linear" way of matching, when the subsequent subpattern does not match the same text as the preceding subpattern.

The `(?!\w)` lookahead works a bit faster than an alternation group `(?:\W|$)` as all it has to do it check if the next char is a word char, and if yes, the match is failed. Actually, in this situation, after `\d`, `(?!\w)` is equal to `\b`, a word boundary, so it is the best construct to use in this position.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5CW*%5Cd%29*%5Cb&i=0000000000000000000000000000Abc%0D%0A---1--2-3--4--5-6).